# Issue with Hidden Div Not Displaying After Reloading

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a simple AJAX function for updating some fields, and after that, I need to reload my div to display the new information. These divs are always initially set to "hidden," so after the update, I need to show them again. However, it is not functioning as expected.

```
<div class="itemG hidden><div>
```

and ajax function is:

```
        function UpdatePhotoInformation(PhotoId) {
        pageWaitMe("progress"); // loading process starts
        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            postType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 'Id': PhotoId},
            url: 'myAction',
            success: function (data) {
                // something ...                 
            }
        }).always(function () {    
            $("#containerPhotos").load(window.location + " #containerPhotos");            
        }).ajaxStop(function () {
            $('.itemG').prop('hidden', false);
        });
    }
```

I tried using the following code in all AJAX events, such as "always," "done," "ajaxComplete," and even "ajaxStop," but none of them worked!

```
$('.itemG').prop('hidden', false);
```

I think there is an asynchronous problem with:

```
$("#containerPhotos").load(window.location + " #containerPhotos");
```

and

```
$('.itemG').prop('hidden', false);
```

Comment: `$("#containerPhotos").load(window.location + " #containerPhotos", function() { $(this).show()});`

Comment: But why do AJAX and then reload? Why not just return the HTML for the div in the success of the first AJAX and then show().